# Restoring a Backup to a different Server - User Permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup, ssms, database-restore

I have backed up and restored a MS SQL Server 2005 database to a new server.

**What is the best way of recreating the login, the users, and the user permissions?**

On SQL Server 2000's Enterprise Manager I was able to script the logins, script the users and script the user permissions all seperately.  I could then run one after the other and the only remaining manual step was to set the login password (which do not script for security reasons)

This does not seem possible in SQL Server 2005's Management Studio, making everything very fiddly and time consuming.  (I end up having to script the whole database, delete all logins and users from the new database, run the script, and then trawl through a mixture of error message to see what worked and what didn't.)

Does anyone have any experience and recommendations on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with Microsoft's `sp_help_revlogin`, a stored procedure that scripts all SQL Server logins, defaults and passwords, and keeps the same SIDs.

You can find it in this knowledge base article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/918992

Comment: Doesn't appear to do the user permissions though.  (Such as GRANT EXECUTE and GRANT SELECT, etc, etc.)

Comment: Right, because that's contained in each individual database, not at the server level.  If you back up a database, do sp_help_revlogin on the old server, use that generated T-SQL on the new server, and then do the restores, you're done.

Comment: The "users" in the restored database still appear to be orphaned from their "logins".

Comment: That's because you didn't do it in order.  You have to create the users via sp_help_revlogin BEFORE restoring the database.  If the users exist now, drop them because they have the wrong sids.

Comment: This may cause a problem because the user's default language is not scripted. If the script is executed, the new login's default language may have changed from whatever it originally was to the server's default language. This failed for us with an, obviously poorly designed, third party application which inserted strings into fields of type datetime. That means that the conversion result depends on the login's default language. After the automatic language change from german to english, month and day were swapped over for all days < 12, and an error was thrown for all days between 13 and 31.

Comment: @BrentOzar - if the sp_help_revlogin is done before restoring the dbs, then it may fail because sometimes the user has a default db that must exist. What do you think?

Comment: @variable you can script them without a default database, and then set the default database later.

Answer (score 2):

Run this:

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Report'
```

This will show a list of all Orphaned users, for example:

[image]

Now execute this script here for each user, for example

```
exec sp_change_users_login 'Update_One', 'UserNameExample', 'UserNameExample'
```

This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use the SQL Compare product from Red Gate (http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm). There are other similar products around but I've had no reason to look for one as SQL Compare has never let me down.

You'll find it is useful for a lot more than the your current requirement as it will help synchronize all types of database object, not just login and permissions.

Comment: We have a similar "database differential" tool.  Unfortunately our Client does not...